# Pass hash filter to external link (like Isotope but custom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, jquery-isotope

**Example:** If user click on specific link in one page, this link will redirect him to filtered content in a specific area.

> I try to build an custom isotope with simple hide and show classes but now I can not make my links connect with the filtered content of other page. 
>   
>  *The hash is correct but it does not show the filtered content. 
>   Probably I have to do something with **onhashchange** function. Thank you!

```
//Generate URL hash
$('.filter-list .cat-item').on('click', function(){
    var filterAttr = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    location.hash = "filter=" + encodeURIComponent(filterAttr);
});
//Generate URL hash
function getHashFilter(){
    var currentHash = location.hash.match( /filter=([^&]+)/i );
    var filterValue = currentHash && currentHash[1];
    return filterValue;
}
function onHashChange(){

    var hashFilter = getHashFilter();

   /* if ( hashFilter ) {
      $container.isotope({ filter: hashFilter });
    }
   */
}
onHashChange();
window.onhashchange = onHashChange;
```

Comment: Looks like a typo in the last line. You've got `onhaschange` instead of `onhashchange`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but this was only on the post.

Comment: `hashFilter` in the `onHashChange` function looks like a local variable. How were you planning to use its value? Seems like some critical part of the code is missing.

Comment: Yes, I need to find out how to replace the `$container.isotopte etc.` with custom filter I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Topic closed. Below the full set of code for custom isotope grid filter.

```
//redirect link with js external document
$("#menu-product").click(function(){ 
    window.location.href = "shops.php#filter=product"; 
});

if (location.hash == "#filter=product") 
{ 
    $(".shop").not(".product").hide(); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".cat-item").click(function(){

   var value =  $(this).attr("data-filter");
   if(value == "all") {
     $(".shop").show();
   }
   else
   {
     $(".shop").not("."+value).hide();
     $(".shop").filter("."+value).show();
   }});
   //Active class
    $("ul .cat-item").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
    });

}); 
//Generate URL hash
$('.filter-list .cat-item').on('click', function(){
    var filterAttr = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    location.hash = "filter=" + encodeURIComponent(filterAttr);
});

function getHashFilter(){
    var currentHash = location.hash.match( /filter=([^&]+)/i );
    var filterValue = currentHash && currentHash[1];
    return filterValue;
}

function onHashChange(){
    var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
}
```